# how can I do a "locate non-coincident" query in Linq?

Tags: .net, linq

Supose I have a table "available_cars" [car_id, descritpion] and another table "cars_x_client" [client_id, car_id]. How can I query all the cars that the client doesn't have?

I know do it in SQL. Maybe it is a piece of cake, but I don't know how to do it in Linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this efficiently you can use a join - this will be translated to an inner join in SQL:

```
var query = from available in available_cars
    join client_car in cars_x_client on available.car_id equals client_car.car_id
    where client_car.client_id != my_client_id
    select car;
```

There are also mechanisms available for outer joins - e.g. if there's a car which doesn't belong to any client then use something like:

```
var query = from available in available_cars
    join client_car in cars_x_client on available.car_id equals client_car.car_id into outer_join
    from outer in outer_join.DefaultIfEmpty
    where (outer == null || outer.client_id != my_client_id)
    select car;
```

For more on linq including joins I recommend 101 linq examples - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx

Comment: I used the ".Except" method to retrieve the diferences between the two datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Try something this.

```
from car in available_cars
where !cars_x_client.Any(x => x.client_id == client_id 
                         && x.car_id == car.car_id)
select car;
```